# Wireless keeps disconnecting on Parch (Arch-based) - RTL8821CE

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, realtek

Every time I try to connect to Wi-Fi, everything is disconnected and this message appears. It may connect itself after a few minutes.

It disconnects and says: "*Connection [name] deactivated*."

then immediately another message says: "*Authorization supplicant timed out*"

[image: Authorization supplicant timed out]

```
[ali@parch ~]$ lspci 
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 08)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (rev 07)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 08)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX110] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
04:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5763DL NVMe SSD Controller (DRAM-less) (rev 01)
```

```
[ali@parch ~]$ sudo dmesg
[  638.538452] wlo1: authenticate with 98:48:27:ff:ff:ff
[  639.150184] wlo1: send auth to 98:48:27:ff:ff:ff (try 1/3)
[  639.152209] wlo1: authenticated
[  639.152517] wlo1: associating to AP 98:48:27:ff:ff:ff with corrupt probe response
[  639.156827] wlo1: associate with 98:48:27:ff:ff:ff (try 1/3)
[  639.162592] wlo1: RX AssocResp from 98:48:27:ff:ff:ff (capab=0x431 status=0 aid=5)
[  639.162855] wlo1: associated
[  640.012254] wlo1: deauthenticating from 98:48:27:ff:ff:ff by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
```

I've installed the [`rtl8821ce-dkms-git`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/rtl8821ce-dkms-git) AUR package too, but it didn't help. I've also removed the `broadcom-wl-dkms` package.

I don't know what other information I need to put here to identify my problem, if you need other information, please tell me and I will provide it to you.

I'm a bit new to Linux, so I couldn't do anything special. I also could not find an answer to this problem on the internet.